# Netezza foreign key constraint

Tags: netezza

Why Netezza does not 'enforce' foreign key constraints although it has the concept of foreign keys? What is the advantage in not enforcing the contraint?

Answer (score 6):

`Foreign Keys` are still used by the query optimizer to help build the most efficient query plan while estimating the cost of a query.  It is also important to use `Foreign / Primary Keys` to take advantage of the many database visualization tools including Microsoft Visio.  The advantage of not enforcing the constraint is speed.  Netezza is able to squeeze extra performance by not maintaining this functionality.

[Netezza Manual](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_using_constraints.html)

Answer (score 0):

Testing Netezza SQL: FOREIGN KEY  clause

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
NOTICE:  foreign key constraints not enforced       <-- Netezza SQL Parser complains here
 */
/* Start time 4/25/2013 6:21:32 PM, end time 4/25/2013 6:21:32 PM. */
/* Duration 0.078125 sec. */
CREATE TABLE table2ref
(
        col1    smallint NOT NULL
       ,colref2 smallint
       ,col3      varchar(30 )
  ,CONSTRAINT fk_column_colref2                                      <-- THIS IS REF CONSTRAINT
   FOREIGN KEY (colref2) 
   REFERENCES test2delete (col1)                     <-- the ref table must already be created 
);

/* Start time 4/25/2013 6:21:32 PM, end time 4/25/2013 6:21:37 PM. */
/* Duration 4.53125 sec. */                         <-- Observe how long the INSERT takes
/* Records Affected: 1. */

insert into table2ref values (3,12345,'reftabstring'); <-- THIS IS NON-EXISTING KEY "12345"

/* Start time 4/25/2013 6:21:37 PM, end time 4/25/2013 6:21:39 PM. */
/* Duration 2.65625 sec. */                         <-- Observe how long the INSERT takes
/* Records Affected: 1. */

insert into table2ref values (3,12345,'reftabstring');
```